# Quickbuild - how to securely set up an agent on a different subnet?

Tags: quickbuild

I am new to quickbuild.

The company has a quickbuild server installed in-house.

I need to run some workflows directly on the cloud. So I installed an agent. but I could not get the server to recognize the agent. I assume the following:

- the communication's direction is from agent to server. The agent registers itself in the server because I cannot find a way to tell the server where the agent is, but I can define the server's location in the agent.
- the company's firewall blocks communication from agent to server.

So my question is how do I make it work? I am investigating several paths to resolve this and would appreciate someone with experience to help me advance on the issue.

Here are the solutions I thought about and their problems:

- Is there a configuration that I can tell the server where the agent is and so the communication is from the server to agent and then I won't experience firewall issues? I tried looking for it, but couldn't find such configuration. If there is a way to do this, how can I prevent others to use this agent?
- To convince the IT team to remove firewall restrictions to quickbuild, I must provide some sort of a secured method for this. For example - give the agent a secret key which is defined in the server. kinda like when you want an application to use your google account - so you go to security and get a one-time key. Is there anything similar in quickbuild?

The quickbuild server is a crucial part of our development cycle, and we cannot replace it with other solutions such as Travis CI, so please don't suggest that. Thanks.

We are using quickbuild 4.

Thanks.